# How to import BIT type to SQL from Powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv

I am trying to import a CSV to SQL Server with PoSh. The file has some columns that I am ignoring so I am using Select-Object to just get the columns needed. This works fine until the SQL table has a Bit type. I get this error:

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type bit of the specified target column.

When I try to cast the column I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store `<True>` in Refrig Column.  Expected type is Boolean.

I have tried [Int32] as well, with similar results.

Code that generates the second error:

`(Import-Csv -path "c:\pathtoSCV\file.csv" -Header 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'colBIT' | select-object 'col1', 'col3', @{name='colBIT';expression={[bool]$_.colBIT}}) | Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "serverName" -Database "" -TableName "tableN"`

CSV example:

```
"C917","","Bob D Hardy","0"
"C43817","","Helen Boch","1"
"C8482f7","","John Smith","1"
```

I am new to PowerShell so any tips are appreciated.

**Update**

Tried

`Expression={[System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean]$_.Refrig}`

and got:

> 'dataType' argument cannot be null

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the CSV?

Comment: Added example csv rows. Thanks

Comment: You're missing a `=` and a `}`. `@{name='colBIT';expression{[bool]$_.colBIT}` should be `@{name='colBIT';expression={[bool]$_.colBIT}}`

Comment: Typo from obfuscation, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think the issue is the difference between SQL bit data type (which allows 1, 0 and *null*) and the PoSh boolean data type (which allows true and false).  [RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/bit-of-a-problem/) have blogged about the problems a nullable boolean-like type causes before.  I tried converting the `[bool]` to a `[Nullable[Boolean]]` but that didn't work.  [Nulls really are a billion dollar mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare).